# Narro API:: message: 'Unauthorized'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I was trying to work with **Narro API** and **MEAN stack**. I have some text articles. I want to convert my text data to audio. From the requirements, it should use [Narro.co](https://www.narro.co/) for audio conversion. From their [documentation](http://docs.narro.co/?javascript#introduction), I started with authentication.

Here is the code,

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.narro.co/api/v1',
    headers: {
        authorization: 'Bearer <access_token>'
    }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(body);
});
```

We can generate the **clientId** and **clientSecret** from the [Narro developer account](https://www.narro.co/account).

> The ClientId(sample) :
>   **921edefq-540y-4g75-be2c-2ade450dc503**
>
> The clientSecret(sample):
>   **a904efd2-a362-4cc5-80qe-262b24728b47743e244e-e39c-44e7-a479-3f0bt3445245**

But it is not working.

I always end up with -

```
{ errors: [ { message: 'Unauthorized' } ] }
```

If it is not the right method, Please suggest me the best way to use Narro API with authentication.

Comment: A client secret is not an access token. You'll need to request one from the Narro API using your client secret. [Narro API Documentation - Authentication](https://docs.narro.co/#authentication)

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow proper OAuth 2.0 flows.It would seem you want to use the Client Credential flow for your purposes, if you're not doing actions on behalf of a user.

I hope the ClientID and Secret there aren't actually yours.

Their own documentation page links to https://oauth.net/2/ which is where you can learn about the different flows, how to request a Bearer token, and how to then use that token to access the API endpoints. (Basically, read the docs...)